# How do I create a javascript elite planet name generator?

Tags: javascript

I try to convert [Tricky's script](http://lpmuds.net/smf/index.php?topic=488.0) (that generates a name from elite) to javascript here:

https://github.com/rubo77/eliteNameGen/blob/master/elite.js

But I get stuck at this [LPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPC_programming_language)-code by Tricky:

```
digrams=ABOUSEITILETSTONLONUTHNO..LEXEGEZACEBISOUSESARMAINDIREAERATENBERALAVETIEDORQUANTEISRION
...
pairs = digrams[24..<1];
...
names[0..<2]
```

I couldn't find a manual to LPC that would explain this syntax.

In the End I want to create a javascript, that creates a random planet name from the old C64 game Elite.

I also found a [python version](https://github.com/jabbalaci/Elite/blob/9eeea969ee275a83563f1cbb2d94faf2daa14190/pyplanets.py), (but that seems a bit more complicated to me)

Comment: This looks like fun, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @rubo77 I did some research and it looks like there's some bit-shifting trickery, which is awesome, since I've always wanted to find an excuse to use bit-shifting and bit-masking in JavaScript. Thanks for posting this question!

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/BonsaiDen/5897243) uses the elite syllables.

Comment: @mister_rampage: you are welcome ;) Only remains, how does LPC work? what does this mean? `digrams[24..<1]`

Comment: @fzzylogic: that seems a bit unfinished (it only generates max 6 letter names)

Comment: @rubo77: As best as I can tell from [here](http://www.mars.org/home/rob/docs/IntermediateLPC/chapter5.html) and [here](http://www.geas.de/tutorial/lpc_44.html). In LPC you can take a subset of an array by using the range operator `..`. So array[2..4] gives you a new array starting at index 2 and running up to index 4 of the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I managed to port the code over, but I had to tweak a bit of the algorithm. The one that is provide by Tricky, for some reason, produces non-unique names. I used the tweakseed function to tweak the seeds to generate a list of random names.

## Answer

To answer the question above, @MattBurland is correct. You would replace the following code:

```
pairs = digrams[24..<1];
```

with

```
pairs = digrams.substring(24);
```

The following code, however, is actually printing out the list of names. So you're indexing an array - in which case:

```
names[0..<2]
```

becomes

```
for (var i = 0; i < (names.length - 2); i++) {
  names[i]
}
```

### Analysis

Just to give this some more depth. I've analyzed the code and realized that `rotatel`, `twist`, `tweakseed`, and `next` were just used to create random numbers. I don't know enough about LPC, but I think that at the time it probably didn't have a pseudo-random number generator.

A lot of this code can be removed and just replaced with `Math.random`. The key part of this entire program is the variable `digram`. This sequence of characters produces Alien-like names. I figure it probably has something to do with alternation of consonants and vowels. Grabbing them in pairs randomly will almost always produce some sort of consonant + vowel pairing. There is the odd time where you'll end up with a name like 'Rmrirqeg', but in most cases, the names appear Alien-like.

### Port

Below is a direct port of the code. You can use this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tgja/) to see it in action, but it uses AngularJS to print out the names instead of printing out a list like the code provided. genNames will produce an array of names, which you can use for whatever reason you want.

Note this port only works on IE9+, since it uses map, reduce, and forEach. Replace these with loops if you plan on using this on IE8 or below.

You can tweak this to produce names longer or shorter. However, the length of the names is dependent on the pairs array. Either use Math.random or something to make it completely wild.

```
var digrams = "ABOUSEITILETSTONLONUTHNO" +
    "..LEXEGEZACEBISOUSESARMAINDIREA.ERATENBERALAVETIEDORQUANTEISRION";

function rotatel(x) {
    var tmp = (x & 255) * 2;
    if (tmp > 255) tmp -= 255;
    return tmp;
}

function twist(x) {
    return (256 * rotatel(x / 256)) + rotatel(x & 255);   
}

function next(seeds) {
    return seeds.map(function(seed) {
        return twist(seed);
    });
}

function tweakseed(seeds) {
    var tmp;

    tmp = seeds.reduce(function(total, seed) {
        return total += seed;        
    }, 0);

    return seeds.map( function ( seed, index, arr ) {
        return arr[index + 1] || (tmp & 65535)
    });
};


function makename(pairs, seeds)
{
    var name = [];
    /* Modify pair if you want to have names shorter or longer than 8 chars */
    /* I'll leave that as an exercise for you. */
    var pair = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    var longname = seeds[0] & 64;

    pair = pair.map(function() {
       seeds = tweakseed(seeds);
       return 2 * ((seeds[2] / 256) & 31);  
    });

    pair.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
        if (longname || ( index < (arr.length - 1))) {
            name.push(pairs[value]);
            name.push(pairs[value + 1]);
        }
    });

    return name.join('').toLowerCase()
            .replace(/^\w/,  function(letter) {
                return letter.toUpperCase(); 
            });
}

function genNames()
{
    var names = [];
    var pairs;
    var num = 256;
    var seeds = [23114, 584, 46931];
    pairs = digrams.substring(24);

    while (--num) {
        names.push( makename(pairs, seeds) );
        seeds = tweakseed(next(seeds));
    }

    return names;
}
```

Comment: cool, I managed to make it run also a bit now [**here**](https://github.com/rubo77/eliteNameGen/blob/master/elite.js), but you seem to have it more in detail. Can you make it create a bit longer names by random sometimes too? And get rid of the dots at the start and end

Comment: I'm just messing with that now. What you need to do is create a random number and set that as the length of the pairs array in the makename function. Since, map and forEach are used, it'll naturally pick up the new length and work with it. Give it a try. If you can't, you can cheat and look at the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Tgja/1/ I do recommend trying to figure it out yourself as it'll much more gratifying when you figure it out. :)

Comment: To get rid of the dots, just remove them from digrams.

Comment: @rubo77 So I had a lot of fun with this question, that I re-wrote the algorithm using Underscore.js - I'm learning underscore. Anyway, I thought I'd share the link with you in case you were interested. http://jsfiddle.net/7Tgja/2/

Answer (score 3):

For the range operator in LPC, this link helps:

http://www.unitopia.de/doc/LPC/operators.html

> ```
>     expr1[expr2..expr3] Extracts a
>                     piece from an array or string.
>                     expr2 or expr3 may be omitted, default is the begin
>                     or end of expr1.
>                     Negative numbers for expr2 or expr3
>                     mean ``count from before the beginning'', i.e.
>                     foo[-2..-1] is an empty array or string.
>                     foo[<2..<1] gives the 2nd and last element of
>                     the array resp. chars of the string.
> ```

So I'm guessing that:

```
pairs = digrams[24..<1];
```

Means get the substring starting at index `24` to the end of the string?